# How to pull tuples out of a list and make a turtle connect it as coordinates?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, turtle-graphics

Write a function called connectTheDots that takes in a list of tuples as its input and an optional color input as well. The default color value should be black. Each tuple is a coordinate pair (x, y) for a turtle. The function will have the turtle trace out a picture by starting at the first coordinate and then moving to each coordinate in turn.

Your function should do the following:

a. Create a turtle, setting the turtle’s color and speed appropriately

b. Check if the input list is empty: if it is empty then nothing else should happen!

c. Without leaving a line behind, move the turtle to the first location given in the list. Then start leaving a line again. Note: recall how to pull values out of a list, and also know that the goto method can take a single (x, y) tuple as its input: myTurtle.goto( (25, 25) ) will move myTurtle to x = 25 and y = 25.

d. After the turtle is at the starting coordinate, move it to each coordinate in the list in turn.

This is what I have been able to do so far:

def connectTheDots(list1, color ="black"):

```
myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle.speed(1)
myTurtle.goto(list1[0])
for x,y in list1[1:]: #I'm unsure if this is correct
   myTurtle.goto(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have most of what you need but are probably making it more complicated than needed and are missing some small details.

For **step "a"** you need to explicitly set the color (you passed it in just fine).  You are probably better off using a symbolic speed instead of a numeric one.

For **step "b"**, if you have a proper `for ... in` loop, you don't need to explicitly check if the list is empty as the loop won't run if it is.  Your splitting off the first item `myTurtle.goto(list1[0])` works against you here as there may not be one, causing an `IndexError`.

For **step "c"** you need to add another command.  Turtles start life in the center of the screen with their pens down.  You need to raise the pen up after creating your turtle.  But you don't need to explicitly move to the starting position, let your loop handle that.

The trick we'll use for **step "c"** and **step "d"** is to put the pen down after the `goto()` in the loop.  The first time, this actually puts the pen down, after that, it's a harmless no-op:

```
import turtle

def connectTheDots(coordinates, color="black"):
    myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
    myTurtle.speed("slowest")
    myTurtle.color(color)
    myTurtle.penup()

    for coordinate in coordinates:
        myTurtle.goto(coordinate)
        myTurtle.pendown()  # redundant after first iteration

dots = ((34, 56), (100, 240), (230, 105), (34, 56))

connectTheDots(dots, "green")

turtle.done()
```

If it bothers you that we're putting the pen down unnecessarily in the loop, then we can replace `myTurtle.pendown()` with:

```
if not myTurtle.isdown():
            myTurtle.pendown()
```